# Permissions for linux program

Tags: redhat

In my work, i have a program dcstart.sh on Redhat linux, that needs to have permission to access higher directory to be successfully executed.
Program needs not only the permission to its application directory, but also to higher directory /aplikace:

```
/aplikace/DC/dcstart.sh
```

Is this common practice to all linux applications, or during some specific conditions ? Could somebody please explain how does this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need permissions to access the complete path to a file to read or execute it. For directories, this means that you need read at least  execute permissions for every directory above the file you want to read or execute.

For directories, you need execute permissions to access anything in it and read permissions to read the list of files or subdirs in that directory.